# Запрос к БД выводящий общие значения

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется таблица: t_s (id, teacherid, studentid).

Выполняю к ней запрос: `SELECT teacherid, studentid, GROUP_CONCAT(studentid ORDER BY studentid ASC SEPARATOR ', ') FROM t_s GROUP BY teacherid`

Получаем вот такой вот вывод: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим что у пятого и девятого учителя, есть общие ученики.

Как построить запрос, что-бы вывод был в итоге вот такой(не обязательно что это будет пятый или девятый учитель):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "_одинаковых студентов_"?

Comment: А почему у учителя должны быть одинаковые студенты?

Comment: Например: 
У учителя с id 1 будут студенты с id 1, 2, 3, 4
У учителя с id 3 будут студенты с id 1, 2, 3, 5

Нужно вывести id учителей, и id их общих студентов, т.е. teacherid 1,2 и studentid 1,2,3

Comment: Неправильно сформулировал свой вопрос, извиняюсь, переформулировал его.

Comment: внёс дополнения в ответ на основании дополнений в вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно сделать примерно так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa367/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (id int);

create table s (id int);

create table t_s (t int, s int);

insert into t values (1), (2), (3), (4);

insert into s values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);

insert into t_s values
   (1, 1)
  ,(1, 2)
  ,(1, 3)
  ,(1, 4)
  ,(2, 4)
  ,(2, 5)
  ,(2, 6)
  ,(3, 1)
  ,(3, 2)
  ,(3, 3)
  ,(4, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.id as `учитель1`, t2.id as `учитель2`, count(*) as `количество`
from t t1
join t_s ts1
  on ts1.t = t1.id
join t_s ts2
  on ts2.s = ts1.s
join t t2
  on t2.id = ts2.t and t2.id > t1.id
group by t1.id, t2.id
order by `количество` desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa367/2/0)**:

```
| id | id | количество |
|----|----|------------|
|  1 |  3 |          3 |
|  1 |  4 |          1 |
|  3 |  4 |          1 |
|  1 |  2 |          1 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select t1.id as `учитель1`, t2.id as `учитель2`, count(*) as `количество`
from t t1
join t_s ts1
  on ts1.t = t1.id
join t_s ts2
  on ts2.s = ts1.s
join t t2
  on t2.id = ts2.t and t2.id > t1.id
group by t1.id, t2.id
order by `количество` desc
limit 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa367/2/1)**:

```
| id | id | количество |
|----|----|------------|
|  1 |  3 |          3 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select concat(t1.id, ', ', t2.id) as `учителя`
 , group_concat(ts1.s order by ts1.s separator ',')
 as `студенты`
from t t1
join t_s ts1
  on ts1.t = t1.id
join t_s ts2
  on ts2.s = ts1.s
join t t2
  on t2.id = ts2.t and t2.id > t1.id
group by t1.id, t2.id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa367/2/2)**:

```
| учителя | студенты |
|---------|----------|
|    1, 3 |    1,2,3 |
```

в первом запросе — общий список совпадений, отсортированный по количеству совпадений, во втором — только первая строка из того запроса, в третьем — ответ на уже переформулированный вопрос.

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но что такое t1, t2 и ts1, ts2?

Comment: это псевдоним (alias) таблицы. см. [синтаксис конструкции *from*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm140215604415584): `FROM tbl_name [[AS] alias]` (аналогичный синтаксис и у *join*). ключевое слово `as` обычно опускают.

Comment: sql запросы, довольно такие непросты. А как модифицировать данный запрос что-бы вместо id, выводились имена, которые хранятся в таблицах t и s?

Comment: `select concat(t1.name, ', ', t2.name) ...`, а таблица `s` в запросе не участвует. её можно связать с таблицей `ts1`, добавив ещё один `join`: `join s on s.id = ts1.s`, и, соответственно, `group_concat(ts1.s` заменить на: `group_concat(s.name ...`.

Comment: @B.Yakushev, я бы всё-таки рекомендовал освоить теорию, начав с **простых** примеров. обращаясь же к окружающим с просьбами составить за вас **сложные** запросы, вы, как мне кажется, лишь усугубляете ваше непонимание.